# TypeConverter for generic type used in xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I am looking into initializing members of generic types declared in XAML. This is targeting the [(reduced) generics support](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/05/20/yes-xaml2009-isn-t-everywhere-yet.aspx) in WPF 4 and future Silverlight. (I have tried the scenarios below using `x:TypeArguments` and `XamlReader.Load` in VS2010 Beta 2, but will use `TestClassInt32 : TestClass<int> { }` for simplicity, as it has the same behavior as using the generic type directly, but is easier to test using compiled xaml today.)

---

Here are the test types I am using.

```
public class TestClass<T> {
  [TypeConverter( typeof(StringListToItemsConverter) )]
  public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
  public TestProperty<T> Property { get; set; }
}

[TypeConverter( typeof(TestPropertyConverter) )]
public struct TestProperty<T> {
  public TestProperty( T value ) : this() { Value = value; }
  public T Value { get; }
}
```

Here is the example scenario.

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel.DataContext>
    <test:TestClassInt32 Items="1,2,3" Property="6" />
  </StackPanel.DataContext>

  <TextBox Text="{Binding Property.Value}" />
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</StackPanel>
```

When I hard-code `typeof(int)` into the converters for this example, everything works fine, but that approach obviously does not work for `TestClass<double>` or `TestClass<DateTime>`. The problem is that the `TypeConverter.ConvertFrom` method does not have access to the destination type, only the source type. (This was not a problem when `TypeConverter` was created in .NET 1.0, because the destination type could not be parameterized, but is an unfortunate limitation now.)

---

Here are the approaches I have looked at to get around this problem:

1. Make the type converter generic; e.g. `[TypeConverter( typeof(TestPropertyConverter<T>) )]`

   - .NET does not support type parameters in attributes
   - Have the `TypeConverter` return an intermediate type that either implements `IConvertible.ToType`, or [has a `TypeConvert` that can `ConvertTo` the destination type](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/declartivegenerics.aspx?msg=927258)
   - XAML parser only does one-step conversions: if the returned object cannot be assigned to the destination, it throws an exception
   - Define a custom type descriptor that will return the appropriate converter based on the actual type
   - WPF ignores custom type descriptors, and `TypeDescriptor` does not even exist in Silverlight

Here are the alternatives I have come up with for "working around" this issue:

1. Require the destination type to be embedded in the string; e.g. `"sys:Double 1,2,3"`

   - In Silverlight, have to hard-code a fixed set of supported types (in WPF, can use the `IXamlTypeResolver` interface to get the actual type that `"sys:Double"` corresponds to)
   - Write a custom markup extension that takes a type parameter; e.g. `"{List Type={x:Type sys:Double}, Values=1,2,3}"`
   - Silverlight does not support custom markup extensions (it also does not support the `x:Type` markup extension, but you could use the hard-coded approach from option 1)
   - Create a wrapper type that takes a type parameter and re-defines all of the generic members as `object`, forwarding all member accesses to the underlying strongly-typed object
   - Possible, but makes for a very poor user experience (have to cast to get underlying generic object, have to still use hard-coded list for type parameter on Silverlight, have to cache member assignments until the type argument is assigned, etc, etc; generally loses most of the benefits of strong typing with generics)

---

Would be happy to hear any other ideas for working around this issue today, or in WPF 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .NET 4, there is an `IServiceProvider` available through which you can get [`IDestinationTypeProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.idestinationtypeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx), and then you should be able to do what you need.
In .NET 3 or 4, the [`IProvideValueTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.iprovidevaluetarget(v=vs.110).aspx) service can give you the targetObject and targetProperty.  From the targetProperty (a `PropertyInfo`, `MethodInfo`-for attached, or a `DependencyProperty`), you can get the type.

To get the`IDestinationTypeProvider` service provider from within `ConvertFrom` of a `TypeConverter` for example:

```
public override object ConvertFrom(
    ITypeDescriptorContext context,
    CultureInfo culture,
    object value )
{
    var typeProvider =
      (IDestinationTypeProvider)context.GetService( typeof( IDestinationTypeProvider ) );
    Type targetType = typeProvider.GetDestinationType();

    // ... do stuff

    return base.ConvertFrom( context, culture, value );
}
```

Comment: Yeah sure, you can have more awesome... but not for 4 months. I can't wait for .Net 4.

Comment: I had tested the `IProvideValueTarget` service earlier in VS2008, but `TargetObject` and `TargetProperty` always returned `null` (and the big "this type is used internally" callout in the documentation led me to believe it was not usable). I re-tested them in VS2010/.NET 4 just now and both returned useful results. Thank you!

Comment: I added information and sample code on how to obtain the service provider which was missing. If I state something incorrect here, please feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 1):

[Rob Relyea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724958/590790) works, but unfortunately *relies on services provided by XAML* and will thus not work for other `ITypeDescriptorContext`'s. This also implies you need to reference `System.Xaml`. This is undesirable for type definitions in assemblies which should not reference `System.Xaml`.

I therefore opted instead to apply a special `TypeConverter` to my generic type which redirects its implementation to a converter which is loaded through `TypeDescriptor`. This allows other assemblies (e.g. using XAML) to specify the type converter to be loaded at runtime using:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(
  typeof( SomeGenericType<> ),
  new TypeConverterAttribute( typeof( SomeGenericTypeConverter ) ) );
```

I created [a `RedirectTypeConverter` base class](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.System/ComponentModel/RedirectTypeConverter.cs) for such converters. The key components of the code required to implement this:

```
protected RedirectTypeConverter( Type type )
{
    _type = type;
}

// Other methods are implemented similarly.
public override object ConvertFrom(
    ITypeDescriptorContext context,
    CultureInfo culture,
    object value )
{
    InitializeConverter();
    return _converter.ConvertFrom( context, culture, value );
}

public void InitializeConverter()
{
    if ( _converter != null )
    {
        return;
    }

    _converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( _type );
    if ( _converter.GetType() == GetType() )
    {
        string message = string.Format(
          "Conversion failed. Converter for {0} is missing in TypeDescriptor.", _type );
        throw new InvalidOperationException( message );
    }
}
```

A [full writeup and extended discussion is available on my blog](https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/generic-typeconverter/).